# security message after upgrade to 9.5.17

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

after upgrading to 9.5.17 i get in the reports the following security messages:

Server Response on static files:

```
www.mydomain.de/typo3temp/assets/43cd7f07.tmp/2500f854.html.wrong
   unexpected content-type text/html
www.mydomain.de/typo3temp/assets/43cd7f07.tmp/2500f854.1.svg.wrong
   unexpected content-type image/svg+xml
www.mydomain.de/typo3temp/assets/43cd7f07.tmp/2500f854.php.wrong
   unexpected content PHP content
www.mydomain.de/typo3temp/assets/43cd7f07.tmp/2500f854.php.txt
   unexpected content PHP content
```

what does this mean?

I inspected the folder /typo3temp/assets/ - there is no folder 43cd7f07.tmp

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something with the encryption key or something (just a guess), not sure

Comment: These files are created temporarily and are removed once the checks in the reports module (and the install tool) have finished - that's why you don't find them in the file-system anymore...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error messages you are receiving are part of a security feature that has been integrated into recent TYPO3 v9.5.17 and v10.4.2 releases, see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Feature-91354-IntegrateServerResponseSecurityChecks.html

Basically it means that your current server system

- is evaluating files like `test.php.txt` (`.php` not at the end of the filename) still as PHP content - this can cause a security vulnerability in case somebody manages to upload a similar file (which might be considered as `text/plain` file, but is actually executable PHP code)

  - potentially **remote code execution**
- is serving files like `test.html.wrong` (`.html` not at the end of the filename) still as `text/html` which triggers the browser to execute HTML tags and potential dangerous `<script>` tags

  - potentially **cross-site scripting**

> **Call for action**
>
> In case this is a live and in production server, you should adjust your web server configuration.

The fix is to limit those web server mime-type mapping only to those files having e.g. `.html` at the very end, like shown in this example for the Apache HTTP web server

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html?$">
    AddType text/html .html .htm
</FilesMatch>
```

Find more details and explanation in the TYPO3 security guidelines for server admins at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/Security/GuidelinesAdministrators/Index.html#file-extension-handling

---

#### Update May 17th, 2020

https://gist.github.com/ohader/11d737de95895f8ca16495a8b7001c45 contains examples how to adjust an `.htaccess` file in case settings cannot be changed on a (shared) hosting environment.

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .html .htm
    <FilesMatch ".+\.html?$">
        AddType text/html .html
        AddType text/html .htm
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveType .svg .svgz
    <FilesMatch ".+\.svgz?$">
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg
        AddType image/svg+xml .svgz
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveHandler .php
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        # IMPORTANT: `php-fcgid` is using in THIS example
        # Most probably is different for each individual configuration
        SetHandler php-fcgid
        # SetHandler php-script
        # SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Current handler identifier `php-fcgid` was identified for the example above using a `phpinfo();` and searching for `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_HANDLER]`:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER'] php-fcgid
```

Comment: whow, what an answer!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Couldn't the first 2 blocks (.html, .svg) be added to ./src/public/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess? That way newly created sites would be OK.

Comment: Probably... but please use https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues for reporting bugs and change requests.

Comment: With this configuration one last error persists for `*.php.wrong` files which are still parsed by PHP. I've added `<FilesMatch ".+\.php\.+"> RemoveHandler .php ForceType text/plain</FilesMatch>` to fix it.

Comment: RegExp does not match, it should be `.+\.php\..+` (`.` before last `+`)

Answer (score 4):

For shared hosting it can be quite hard to find out the correct handler for php.

some specialty for 1&1 Ionos, might be even special to this particular shared hosting package:

shared hosting with php 7.3 (confirmed in phpinfo), but $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER'] gives "x-mapp-php5" (not sure why, could be that the hosting is running for many years and was upgraded to php 7 and they somehow alias it for whatever reason)

The working solution for me was:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .html .htm
    <FilesMatch ".+\.html?$">
        AddType text/html .html
        AddType text/html .htm
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveType .svg .svgz
    <FilesMatch ".+\.svgz?$">
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg
        AddType image/svg+xml .svgz
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveType .php
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
        AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I had to remove both the handler/type and add them again within the filesmatch.
Took me quite a while to get this working, hope this helps.

For host-europe $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER'] was empty, php7.4:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    ....

    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveType .php
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        # only this handler seems to work
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following solution was recommended to me by the support team of ALL-INKL.COM.
I had to contact them, because the remove statements (RemoveHandler .php) did not work.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php[0-9,x]*|phtml)\.">
  SetHandler text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks to the ALL-INKL.COM-Support-Team

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Domainfactory speciality.

Mind the `ForceType` directive (set your specific PHP version there). If not used, its webserver would still use mimetype-sniffing.

To be used on the bottom of the newest .htaccess template ([10.4](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess), [9.5](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess)) which includes the strict handling for `.svg[z]`/`.htm[l]` already

```
# DomainFactory-special:
# 1) remove mimetype-sniffing anything for PHP
# 2) force PHP 7.3 mimetype on .php files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .php
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        ForceType application/x-httpd-php73
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for JWEILAND, WEBGO and PHP:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  RemoveHandler .php
  RemoveType .php  
  <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for 1blu

```
RemoveHandler .php
  RemoveType .php  
  <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
     SetHandler fcgid-script
     AddType fcgid-script .php
     AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  </FilesMatch>
```