# <If> condition with HTTP_HOST in htaccess breaks PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, typo3

I'd like to harden my shared hosting webspace to prevent it from rendering PHP with faked filenames like foo.php.wrong as suggested in the [TYPO3 Security Guidelines](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/Security/GuidelinesAdministrators/Index.html#file-extension-handling). For details see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760273/3946047

Since I don't have access to the Apache configuration I'd like to add the configuration to my `.htaccess` file. But to make the `.htaccess` file work on **both**, my local development environment and in production, I need to wrap the code with a `<If>` condition to distinguish between production and all other environments.

But as soon as I add the condition, PHP rendering fails for all PHP files. Instead, the source code is shown. To verify it's not a problem of my huge `.htaccess` file, I created a new subdomain with an empty directory and put this into the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .html .htm
    <FilesMatch ".+\.html?$">
        AddType text/html .html
        AddType text/html .htm
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveType .svg .svgz
    <FilesMatch ".+\.svgz?$">
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg
        AddType image/svg+xml .svgz
    </FilesMatch>

    #<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^(.+)example\.com$/">
    RemoveType .php
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        AddType application/x-httpd-php73 .php
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php73
    </FilesMatch>
    #</If>
</IfModule>
```

This works as long as the condition is commented out. When I activate the condition, even valid PHP files like index.php only show the source code instead of being rendered.

The special type `application/x-httpd-php73` is needed because my provider offers several PHP versions.

So my problem is not the configuration itself but the condition. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Just some ideas: 1) ‹If› needs Apache 2.4+. 2) Although probably not the problem, the condition could be a bit simpler: `=~ /domain\.tld$/`. For easier testing, you could do a simple Redirect inside an `If` in a plain .htaccess. 3) If you are behind an intransparent reverse proxy, the HOST could even be rewritten to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST (I've only once seen this in the wild, but TYPO3 handles this gracefully)

Comment: _Aside:_ What specifically are you trying to match with the `/^(.+)example\.com$/` regex? (It's just that it's a bit unusual and inefficient.) This matches `<something>example.com` (where `<something>` can be another hostname, not necessarily a subdomain), but does not match the domain apex `example.com`. Consequently, this would be the same as simply `/.example\.com$/` - where the initial unescaped dot is _any character_.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^(.+)example\.com$/">
> RemoveType .php
> <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
>     AddType application/x-httpd-php73 .php
>     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php73
> </FilesMatch>
> #</If>
> ```

This "fails" because the inner `<FilesMatch>` section (inside the `<If>` section), that *re-enables* the PHP handler is never actually processed. This has to do with the [order in which sections are merged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging).

Surrounding the directives in an `<If>` block changes the order of processing. The contents of the `<If>` section are merged very late, *after* `<Files>` (and `<FilesMatch>`) sections are merged. So, it seems that at the time the `<If>` section is processed, it is too late for any child `<Files>` (or `<FilesMatch>`) containers to be processed (since any `<Files>` containers - that are to be processed - have already been processed). Although this is admittedly very counter-intuitive, and there does not appear to be any "warning" of this, as far as I can see, in the Apache docs.

This can be demonstrated with a simple example (which applies to all requests and all files):

```
<If true>
    SetEnv IF_OUTER 1
    <Files *>
        SetEnv IF_INNER_FILES 1
    </Files>
</If>
```

*Without* the `<If>` wrapper, both the `IF_OUTER` and `IF_INNER_FILES` environment vars are set. However, *with* the `<If>` wrapper (causing the block to be merged late), the `IF_INNER_FILES` env var is not set. It doesn't matter what directives are used: mod_setenvif, mod_rewrite, etc. the inner `<Files>` block within the `<If>` section is never processed.

---

However, you could use an alternative method using mod_rewrite to block *malicious* requests of the form `foo.php.wrong`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$
RewriteRule \.php\. - [R=404]
```

Any request to `example.com` (strictly speaking any hostname that ends with `example.com`) that contains `.php.` in the URL-path will simply return a 404.

However, you may need to place this in a different part of your `.htaccess` file. Preferably near the top. You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if it's already present.

---

There may also be other ways you can identify your development server (or rather, the "live server"). eg. You could `Define` a variable in your development server config and check for the *absence* of this using `<IfDefine>` in `.htaccess` instead.

For example, in your development server config:

```
Define DEVELOPMENT_SERVER
```

Then in `.htaccess`, check that this is *not* defined in order to identity the live server:

```
<IfDefine !DEVELOPMENT_SERVER>
    # Processed only on live server...
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: The reason why your original directives did not work is certainly to do with the order of processing (as I initially stated it might be). I've updated my answer with some reasoning as to why.