# TYPO3 Security Warning

Tags: security, typo3, report

in my TYPO3-Installation (11.x) I get this Warning-Message in the BE > Reports/Security

```
Server Response Warnings:
../typo3temp/assets/6134aef7.tmp/22b33623.1.svg.wrong

unexpected content-type image/svg+xml
```

the file and the folder 6134aef7.temp dont exist. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [security message after upgrade to 9.5.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759835/security-message-after-upgrade-to-9-5-17)